# ASP.NET Edit Gridview Row data and update changes in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, webforms

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms project to make and I have a Staff Page that has a Gridview which is populated from the database and I want to enable "Edit Mode" by clicking Edit button which is on each row and then Save the changes into the database by making an UPDATE statement. Which would be the best approach to do this. I am still a junior so please be very generous with details and explanation. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Webforms and gridviews have been around for decades. I think you can [find existing resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx) rather than have someone re-invent the wheel.

Comment: I've seen some approaches, but i don't get to understand which is the best and the most secure. That's why I asked for the best approach, the best practice.

Comment: That's too broad a question and is considered off-topic. Do you really need to use webforms? MVC is much more modern (with many built-in security features) and the experience translates better to any web development work than the web forms paradigm.

Comment: I am taking a detailed course on MVC. This is my last project with webforms and then I will switch to MVC.

Comment: OK, good. In that case how concerned are you really with "best practices"? Find a microsoft example, like I linked to, and go for it is my advice.

Comment: Ok. I'll go for that. Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control). It covers all the basics of GridView editing and updating.